# Array out of bounds - Basic Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning how to program in Java but I can't seem to get past an array problem. 
See, I get an array out of bounds error when I run this program:

I know this is probably really easy to solve but I have no idea what's going on.

```
public class AlturaPromedio {
float alturas[];
int cont;
float promedio;
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

float cargarAlturas() throws IOException {
    alturas = new float[4];
    for (cont = 0; cont < alturas.length; cont++) {
        System.out.println("Escriba el nombre de la primer altura:");
        alturas[cont] = Float.parseFloat(buffRead.readLine());
    }
    return alturas[cont];

}

float calcularPromedio() {
    promedio = (alturas[1] + alturas[2] + alturas[3] + alturas[4] + alturas[0]) / 5;
    return promedio;
}

/*float calcularMaximo(){
    maximo = Alturas.min(alturas);
   */ 
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws IOException {
        AlturaPromedio personas = new AlturaPromedio();
        personas.cargarAlturas();
        personas.calcularPromedio();


}
}
```

Comment: `alturas[4]` attempts to access the fifth `float` in the array, but you've defined the array with only four values.

Comment: Look at the size you picked for alturas. Now count the number of elements of it you reference in calcularPromedio.

Comment: Just change return alturas[cont] --> return alturas[cont - 1]
and alturas = new float[4]; --> alturas = new float[5];

Answer (score 1):

Change the return statement in `cargarAlturas()` function to

```
return alturas[cont-1];
```

And you will be fine. Actually the value of cont after the for `loop` is 4. Since your `array` size is 4 and you are accessing 5th variable,it will give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.`

Comment: He doesn't need to return anything at all from the function. alturas is a global variable and the return value from cargarAlturas is ignored.

Comment: @user814064 yeah, but still as per his definition of method, some float value must be returned. I was suggesting just solution to his problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring that `alturas` array size to 4 and accessing the 5th element `alturas[4]`.
Error prone lines are

```
 return alturas[cont];
```

this should be

```
 return alturas[cont-1];
```

and

```
promedio = (alturas[1] + alturas[2] + alturas[3] + alturas[4] + alturas[0]) / 5;
```

this should be

```
promedio = (alturas[1] + alturas[2] + alturas[3] + alturas[0]) / 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time this line gets executed cont has gone from 0 to 1 to 2 to 3 and then to 4 when the loop ends.

```
return alturas[cont];  // This is an error accessing an element that doesn't exist.
```

Given the way the rest of your program is written it seems like `Alturas` should be `global`. It makes no sense to return a `single element` since you're using the whole `array` here. And this line is running off the end of the `array` as well:

```
promedio = (alturas[1] + alturas[2] + alturas[3] + alturas[4] + alturas[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes that you are referencing `alturas[4]` when the `length` is `4` and it is `0-indexed`

Answer (score 0):

After loop the following `return alturas[cont];` crashes as you try to get the `element` with index "4" from array, but there are only 4 elements, so 3 is `max` valid `index`.
Two more flaws:

- Don't declare all variables in the beginning like in Pascal;
- When error occurs, look at stack trace first.

Answer (score 0):

`alturas[]` has four `elements` only. `alturas[4]` accessing fifth `element`. That is why `array out of bound exception`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this block of code.

```
alturas = new float[4];
for (cont = 0; cont < alturas.length; cont++) {
    System.out.println("Escriba el nombre de la primer altura:");
    alturas[cont] = Float.parseFloat(buffRead.readLine());
}
return alturas[cont];
```

Once the for loop finishes, `cont` has a value of `4`. So `return alturas[cont]` tries to return `alturas[4]`, which causes your array out of bounds error

Answer (score 0):

```
alturas = new float[4];
```

This means that your array alturas has a total of 4 elements... Now if you see this line- promedio = (alturas[1] + alturas[2] + alturas[3] + alturas[4] + alturas[0]) you are trying to access alturas[4] which is actually the 5th element considering 0 as the first element..

Just try this to solve it:

```
alturas = new float[5];
```

Also your return statement should be like this:

```
return alturas[cont-1];
```